# Reactions not working when used to confirm an action

Tags: discord.py

In the following code i have set up the reactions as a confirmation for the next task. That is, if the reaction is `no` then the function does not proceed to append certain data into a dict. Same goes with the `timeout`. When tested, only the timeout works and sends the message that it is supposed to. However, when reacted on one of the reactions nothing happens. First time i am dealing with reactions so not sure what i've messed up.

```py
        yes = '✔'
        no = ''

        for y in yes:
            await message.add_reaction(y)

        for n in no:
            await message.add_reaction(n)

        def check(reaction, user):
            return (reaction.message.id == message.id) and (user.id == ctx.author.id) and (str(reaction) in y) and (str(reaction) in n) 

        try:
            reaction, user = await self.bot.wait_for('reaction_add', check=check, timeout=60)
        except asyncio.TimeoutError:
            await ctx.send("Timed out")
            await message.delete()
            return
        if str(reaction) == '✔':
            await ctx.send('some stuff')
        if str(reaction) == '':
            await ctx.send('canceled')
            return
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your check will always return false,
`(reaction.message.id == message.id) and (user.id == ctx.author.id) and (str(reaction) in y) and (str(reaction) in n)` means that `str(reaction)` should be in both n and y.

Your check should be

```py
def check(reaction, user):
   return (reaction.message.id == message.id) and (user.id == ctx.author.id) and (str(reaction) in y) or (str(reaction) in n)
```

Comment: Oh as simple as that. How did I miss it! Thank you very much.